# How can I upgrade to CocoaPods 1.1 when it has been released now?

Tags: cocoapods

Before it has been released, I think I should use "sudo gem install cocoapods --pre" to accomplish my aim. But now it has been released. Should I still use "sudo gem install cocoapods --pre"?

I consider I should use "sudo gem install cocoapods" to install CocoaPods 1.1. But I failed. After I remove all previous CocoaPods in my Mac and call "sudo gem install cocoapods", I still get CocoaPods 1.0 installed.

What is wrong with my steps before? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check there might be two versions of cocoapods installed. So i recommend to uninstall all the cocoapods old or new version and have a clean install.

To uninstall use this in terminal:

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo gem uninstall
```

or

```
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods && \
gem update --system && \
gem update && \
gem cleanup && \
pod setup
```

Then install CocoaPods it will be installing the latest version and if in case it does not then you can use sudo gem update command to update the Pods.

For installing CocoaPods use,

sudo gem install cocoapods

and if you want to install RC version

sudo gem install cocoapods --pre

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have try above command. But still no luck... It seems I should try "sudo gem install cocoapods --pre"?

Comment: It seems that after I call following command, it succeed finally. 'rm -fr ~/.cocoapods'

Comment: I also had to call 'sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin cocoa pods' for cocoapods 1.1.1 installation.

Comment: Yes. Now CocoaPods version is 1.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that after I call following command, it succeed finally. 'rm -fr ~/.cocoapods'

I also had to call 'sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin cocoa pods' for cocoapods 1.1.1 installation.

Thanks for Parth Adroja's answer. It also helped me a lot.